# Completing level 1 to move on to level 2 in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a website where user has to complete a task and at the end of the task it stores the value `"complete"` in the field `"level1"` in the database. I have `level1 level2 level3 level4`, once level1 is complete the query inputs in level1 `"complete"`, this all works fine. 
But when i go to level2 page if the user has not completed level 1 it redirect them to level 1 which is fine but if they have completed level 1 it still redirects them to level 1. Any help would be appreciated?

Here is the code for level2 page:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 

{
   header("Refresh:5; url=home.php");
   die("PLEASE LOG IN TO ACCESS SERVICES.....Redirecting to home page. Please wait...");
}

if($_SESSION['user']['level1'] != 'complete') {
     header("Refresh:5; url=numbers.php");
    die("PLEASE Complete STAGE 1 to continue to this stage.....Redirecting to Stage 1. Please wait...");    
}
```

Basically if level 1 is complete the current page should load but its redirecting user back to level 1. even if the user has completed level1.

This is code for level1 when completed task:

```
   <?php

require("config.php");



 if($_SESSION['user']['blacklisted_users'] == 'blocked')

 { 

    header("location: blocked.php");
 }

if($_SESSION['user']['type'] == 'admin') 

{ 

    header("location: memberlist.php");

}

   if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 

{

    echo "<script>
    alert('Please Login to access services');
     window.location.href='home.php';
     </script>";

}

 if(!empty($_POST))
{


    if(isset($_POST['level1']))

    {


   $query = "
            SELECT
                1
            FROM users
            WHERE
                level1 = :level1 
        ";


        $query_params = array(
            ':level1' => $_POST['level1']
        );

        try
        {

            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    $stmt->bindValue(':level1 ', $level1, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {

            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }




    $query_params = array(
        ':level1' => $_POST['level1'],
        ':user_id' => $_SESSION['user']['id'],
    );



    $query = "
        UPDATE users
        SET
           level1 = :level1, level1 = 'complete'
    ";

    $query .= "
        WHERE
            id = :user_id
    ";

    try
    {
        // Execute query
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    $stmt->bindValue(":level1" , "$userid", PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {

        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }



    header("Location: words.php");
    die("Redirecting to private.php");
}
}

 ?>
```

Comment: What does `$_SESSION['user']['level1']` output? Are you being redirected to `home.php` or `numbers.php`?

Comment: being redirected to numbers page which is level1.

Comment: not sure how do i check this?

Comment: Try `var_dump($_SESSION['user']['level1']);`.. or `print_r($_SESSION['user']['level1']);`

Comment: So where do you set that value?

Comment: Iv updated on question please have a look at updated question

Comment: There is no `$_SESSION['user']['level1'] = ` in that code. You also don't start your session in that code. Also `$stmt->bindValue(":level1" , "$userid", PDO::PARAM_STR); ` isn't doing anything, query has already been executed there..

Comment: There is a session for user but i do not think there is  for level1.

Comment: Yea, so that's your issue. You are checking `$_SESSION['user']['level1']` but it is NULL/empty.

Comment: iv added the full code for level1 page please have a look

Comment: Same issue, also don't know why are you binding after executing; or binding at all. The `$query_params` is binding.. You never assign `$_SESSION['user']['level1']`..

Comment: $_SESSION['user']['level1'] = $_POST['level1']; would work

Comment: Yes, if you start the session and that value is populated.